# Can't assign to function call - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why Python is throwing a "Can't assign to function call" error for my last line of code. It goes away when I take out everything after the first comma. Is there a better way syntactically to do this?

```
class UserProperty(models.Model):
    state = models.ManyToManyField(), USState, blank=True, null=True
```

Comment: I think you might have misplaced the closing parenthesis in the call to `models.ManyToManyField()`. I think it should have been at the end of the line.

Comment: Did you mean `state = models.ManyToManyField(USState, blank=True, null=True)`?

Comment: Whatever the reason for this particular error message, your code is pure nonsense as is and has no inherent meaning, so it'll result in some error or another. Take a good hard look at it again.

Comment: A general tip for writing and debugging Python code, whenever you have an assignment make sure you have the correct number of variable on either side of the assignment. Presuming `state` is not a tuple then you have different numbers of variables on either side, which will be an error.

Comment: Looking through the Django documentation (if this is Django then edit in the [tag:django] tag) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField you can see some examples of how to use `ManyToManyField` and it fairly clearly explains what parameters are needed and even gives some example code. With Django looking through the docs is often a good starting point as they are very high quality.

Comment: the reason why you are getting the error message is: you are trying to assign state = models.ManyToManyField() and blank=True and null=True and because you dont know the syntax you are doing this in a tuple which will result in a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` (trying to assign a Class in a tuple that is). Just use @frgtn 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should put parenthesis around all the parameters like this:

```
class UserProperty(models.Model):
    state = models.ManyToManyField(USState, blank=True, null=True)
```